# swift tableviewcell button image issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a button in my tableviewcell and when a certain criteria met, I want to change the button image. I have endless scroll for my tableview.

For example, I have 10 cells on the first page. First cell meets the criteria and button icon change displayed correctly. But When I scroll 11.the cells icon was also changed which does not meets the criteria. When I scroll down I observe that 21th, 31th... cells icons also changed.

```
func setupX(){

  let authorID = self.yazar?["author_id"].int!
  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "FavAuthors")
  let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "authorID", ascending: true)
  fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
  let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "authorID == %ld", authorID!)
  fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
  let fetchResults = self.context!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error:  nil) as? [FavAuthors]
  if fetchResults!.count == 0 {
  }else{
     self.followButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "UnFollow Button.pdf"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
  }
}
```

Comment: it is because tableview reuse cells....you must maintain button state on cell to get rid of this

Comment: I have no idea how the code has anything to do with the described problem, but i can still tell what is going wrong: tableViewCells are reused, if a cell moves off-screen and another one moves on-screen there will not be created a new cell, it will reuse the previously dismissed one. If you set the image somewhere outside of `cellForRowAtIndexpath` you will have that previously set content still present if a cell is dequed for a new index path.

Comment: I set it in my custom tableviewcell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the cells are reused with the old state. You should set the image explicitly if it does not meet the criteria.

For example, change:

```
if fetchResults!.count == 0 {
  } else {
     self.followButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "UnFollow Button.pdf"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
  }
```

To:

```
if fetchResults!.count == 0 {
     self.followButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Follow Button.pdf"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
  } else {
     self.followButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "UnFollow Button.pdf"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing the cells as you scroll down your view, so the image set in the first cell will be reused. If you set the image to nil in the if statement it should remove this image when it is reused.

Comment: simple rule of thumb: data must be in model.. so also button state shuold be in array/dict/coredata/NSUrserdfault. non in UI.